# How can I make a service accessible to itself using host IP address inside a Docker container?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have a software (which I can not change) running inside a Docker container (let's say it's service is available in `http://192.168.0.5:8080/x`) on Ubuntu. The software tries to make a connection to itself via host's external IP (let's say through `http://200.200.200.200:8080/x`), without success (connection timeout/no route to host).

Externally I can access the service because the port 8080 is being mapped and exposed to the host.

How can I make the service accessible to itself through host's external IP?

Comment: Seems like a firewall issue to me. Did you try to use internal ip?

Comment: With internal IP it works fine, but I need to access via the external IP.

Comment: It was ineed a firewall issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Firewall issue on the host. After adding all the used ports to the FirewallD the service is accessible though external IP.